# SQL/BigQuery - List of products sold together

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

how are you doing?

I have a sales table with DATE, TICKET_ID (transaction id) and PRODUCT_ID (product sold). I'd like to have a list of the items sold together PER DAY (that is, today product X was sold with product Y 10 times, yesterday product X was sold with product Y 5 times...)

I have this code, however it has two problems:

1- Generate inverted duplicates. Example:

```
product_id    product_id_bought_with  counting
12345         98765                   130
98765         12345                   130
abcde         fghij                   88
fghij         abcde                   88
```

2- This code ran fine WITHOUT THE DATA COLUMN. After I entered the data volume is much larger and I get a limit error.
*"Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 152% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): ORDER BY operations: 99% other/unattributed: 1%"*

My code:

```
  SELECT
    c.DATE,
    c.product_id,
    c.product_id_bought_with,
    count(*) counting
    
    FROM ( SELECT a.DATE, a.product_id, b.product_id as product_id_bought_with
      FROM `MY-TABLE` a
      
      INNER JOIN `THE-SAME-TABLE` b
      ON a.ID_TICKETS = b.ID_TICKETS
      AND a.product_id != b.product_id
      AND a.DATE = b.DATE
    ) c

    GROUP BY DATE, product_id, product_id_bought_with
    ORDER BY counting DESC
```

I'm open to new ideas on how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sample example

```
CREATE TABLE `project_id.dataset.table_name` (
    DAT_VTE DATE,
    ID_TICKET STRING,
    product_id int
);

INSERT INTO `project_id.dataset.table_name` (DAT_VTE, ID_TICKET, product_id)
VALUES 
(DATE('2022-01-01'), '123_abc', 876123),
(DATE('2022-01-01'), '123_abc', 324324),
(DATE('2022-01-02'), '456_def', 876123),
(DATE('2022-01-02'), '456_def', 324324),
(DATE('2022-01-02'), '456_def', 432321),
(DATE('2022-05-23'), '987_xyz', 876123),
(DATE('2022-05-23'), '987_xyz', 324324)
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample data which you are using ?

Comment: Sure! Please check updated description =)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can try the below query:

```
with mytable as(
 
 select *,row_number()over (partition by DAT_VTE,ID_TICKET)rownum from `project_id.dataset.MY-TABLE`
)
 
select DAT_VTE
,product_id
,product_id_bought_with
,count(*) counting
from (
select a.DAT_VTE,a.ID_TICKET,a.product_id as product_id, b.product_id as product_id_bought_with
from mytable a
join mytable b
ON a.ID_TICKET   = b.ID_TICKET       
     AND a.DAT_VTE = b.DAT_VTE
     and a.rownum <b.rownum
)
GROUP BY DAT_VTE, product_id, product_id_bought_with
```

According to the error you provided, resources exceeded errors are usually triggered when an operation  needs to gather all  the data on a single computation unit and if it doesn’t fit in, then the job will fail. Ordering a huge amount of data involves heavy computation resources that can be better utilized if [partitions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute) are used.

Below are the ways to resolve your issue :

1  Usually partition helps with the resources issue as given in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables).

2 You can also try to split your query, write the results of every individual sub/inner query to another table as a temporary storage space for further processing.